# .Net Xml serialization appending negative sign to 0

Tags: c#, xml, .net-3.5, xmlserializer

I am trying to serialize the object which is having properties of type double value but output xml is having the one of the parameter value as "-0".
I am using .Net framework 3.5.

Sample code:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
Public class Data
{
  [XmlElement(Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
  public double Lateral { get; set;}
}

public class Test
{
   Public static void Main()
   {
       Test t=new Test();
       
       Data data=new Data();
       data.Lateral=0;
       string xml = t.ToXml(data);
       Console.WriteLine(xml);

   }
     Public string ToXml(Data data)
     {
         using (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter())
         {
            XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Data));
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(stringWriter, data);
            return stringWriter.ToString();
         }
     }
   }
}

Output xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Data xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Lateral>-0</Lateral>
</Data>
```

Comment: Have you tested a more recent Framework?

Comment: @Jimi I have tried with recent framework, value is coming without negative sign.

Comment: Upgrading to latest framework is restricted in our applications. So looking for the solution in the .net3.5 framework.

Comment: Do you actually need to serialize to XML, or JSON would do? Json.Net has no dependencies targeting .Net Framework 3.5.

Comment: If the data resides in the SQL Server database, you can easily create XML in the database layer.

Comment: @jimi Yes, tightly dependent on XML, we cannot use Json

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky We dont have any SQL database, data is getting created during runtime

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it happens with double 0. you can try a very simple trick

```
public class Data
{
    private double _lateral;

    public double Lateral
    {
        get { return _lateral + 0 ; }
        set { _lateral = value; }
    }

     //or
     public double Lateral
    {
        get { return _lateral; }
        set { _lateral = value + 0 ; }
    }
}
```